# Get string between specified text PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to extract the date and time from this, how would I go about doing that?

My Code

```
    <?php
$url = file_get_contents('http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://unitedseo.ae');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($url);
    $node = $doc->getElementById('google-cache-hdr');
    echo $doc->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

My code returns this

```html
<body><div id="google-cache-hdr" dir="ltr">
<div>This is Google's cache of <a href="http://www.unitedseo.ae/" dir="ltr">http://www.unitedseo.ae/</a>. It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on May 20, 2017 05:16:23 GMT. </div>
<div>The <a href="http://www.unitedseo.ae/" dir="ltr">current page</a> could have changed in the meantime. <a href="http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&amp;p=cached&amp;answer=1687222">Learn more</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
<span style="display:inline-block !important;margin-top:8px !important;margin-right:104px !important;white-space:nowrap !important;"><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><span style="font-weight:bold !important;">Full version</span></span><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://unitedseo.ae&amp;num=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;prmd=ivns&amp;strip=1&amp;vwsrc=0">Text-only version</a></span><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://unitedseo.ae&amp;num=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;prmd=ivns&amp;strip=0&amp;vwsrc=1">View source</a></span></span><span style="display:inline-block !important;margin-top:8px !important;color:#717171 !important;">Tip: To quickly find your search term on this page, press <b>Ctrl+F</b> or <b>⌘-F</b> (Mac) and use the find bar.</span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: show the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$url = file_get_contents('http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://unitedseo.ae');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
$node = $doc->getElementById('google-cache-hdr');
$results = $doc->saveHtml($node);
preg_match("#\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}#", $results, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20 May 2017 05:16:23
)
```

Comment: I just tried that but it all it displays is 'Array( )'

Comment: @LouisDench Just copy paste my code, it is working fine.

Comment: I did, maybe it's the webhost I'm using. The link http://denchmacros.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Still returning just "Array ( )"

Comment: @LouisDench Just check the string which you are getting in your code `echo $doc->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;`?

Comment: It returns what appears in the code snippet above, with "Array()" above it

Comment: @LouisDench The problem was dateformat Can you check this `[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

Answer (score 0):

Regex would probably be the best solution, but I you could also try `strpos` method.

If you would search on the text `appeared on`, get the position then search for the position of `.</div>` you could find out where your time is located and extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://unitedseo.ae');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($url);
    $node = $doc->getElementById('google-cache-hdr');
    echo $rs = $doc->saveHtml($node);
    preg_match('/(\d?\d [A-Za-z]+ \d\d\d\d) (\d\d\:\d\d)/', $rs, $matches);
    echo $matches[0];
    print_r($matches);die;
    die;
?>
```